# In Kubernetes, how can I create a CronJob to test mysql database connectivity from a standard docker image?

Tags: cron, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to create a cronjob in EKS to test the database connection, but it's no working. I tried with the mysql-client docker image.
This is the cronjob definition:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: mysql-test
  namespace: default
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: mysql
            image: imega/mysql-client
            command: ["mysql", "-xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com", "-uxxxxxxx", "-pxxxxxxx", "-e'show databases;'"]
          restartPolicy: Never
```

But it's returning:

`` ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`show databases;`' at line 1 ``

Any idea?

Comment: This command `"-e'show databases;'"` doest not look correct to me. What `-e` stands for? Can you please test it without it? Using just `"show databases"`?

Comment: -e stands for --execute= on mysql cli

Comment: Why have you put in the extra quotes?

Comment: that's how it's documented in usage here:
https://hub.docker.com/r/imega/mysql-client

Comment: Can you try changing `"-e'show databases;'"` into  `"-e", "show databases;"` ?

Comment: Any updates? @McCo0L

Comment: the issue was with Fargate @thomas, thanks.